# About the Stein factorisation of a morphism defined by a complete linear system on a surface, whose image is a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic complex projective surface, and let $D$ be an effective divisor on $X$ with empty base locus. Assume that the morphism $\varphi = \varphi_D : X \to \mathbb P^{h^0(D)-1}$ has image a curve $C$ (a sufficient condition is $D^2=0$). Let
\begin{equation}
X \to \widetilde{C} \to C
\end{equation}
be the Stein factorisation of $\varphi : X \to C$. Now, assume that $h^1(\mathcal O_X) = 0$. Then

> necessarily $\widetilde{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$, and $\widetilde{C}=C$ since $\widetilde{C} \to \mathbb P^{h^0(D)-1}$ is defined by a complete linear system.

Could anyone help me explain (in detail!) this argument?

1. Why is $\widetilde C$ isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$?
2. How do you prove that $\widetilde C = C$, using that $\widetilde{C} \to \mathbb P^{h^0(D)-1}$ is defined by a complete linear system?
3. Why is $\widetilde{C} \to \mathbb P^{h^0(D)-1}$ defined by a complete linear system? What linear system defines that map?

The quotation above is taken from the proof of Theorem 3.8 (b) in [*Chapters on Algebraic surfaces*](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9602006) by M. Reid, page 70. I find it very difficult to understand it.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I found some helpful details in [*Lectures on K3 surfaces*](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/K3Global.pdf) by D. Huybrechts, Proposition 3.10, page 31. Nevertheless, the arguments seem to me quite involved. I wonder if there is some more "elementary" approach.

Comment: For 1, $\tilde{C}$ can't have any 1-forms, since they would pull-back to give 1-forms on $X$. For 2, every complete linear system on  $\mathbb{P}^1$ is very ample, so defines an embedding. For 3, it's the (unique!) complete linear system on $P^1$ which pulls back to $|D|$. Hope that helps!

Comment: You can use Leray spectral sequence for (1).

Comment: How can you use this spectral sequence? It is mentioned in Huybrechts's Paper, also...